# Customer-facing Bug Reporting & Feature Request tools to integrate in C# smartclient

Tags: .net, bug-reporting

I am developing a business smart-client application using c# 3.5 and WinForms.

I am looking for a bug reporting and feature request solution that would allow users to quickly and easily create new bug reports and request new feature enhancements *without leaving the application*.

Are there any pre-existing solutions in this space?